# Spring Boot, Java, Docker Compose, Getting 'Connection refused' while trying to make connection between two container (mysql, my-api)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, r2dbc

When I execute the `docker-compose up command`, the following error is generated:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I am trying to establish a connection between two containers, MySQL and My-API container, using docker-compose, but it is somehow not connecting. Here is the docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  discovery-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.34
    container_name: discovery-mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=tomo
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=r2dbc
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    networks:
      - common-network

  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway
    command:
      - url=jdbc:mysql://discovery-mysql:3306/r2dbc?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false -user=root -password=tomo migrate
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources/db/migration:/flyway/sql
      - ./flyway/conf/flyway.config:/flyway.config
    depends_on:
      - discovery-mysql
    networks:
      - common-network

  discovery-app:
    image: tomojava3284/helloworldapi:latest
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - discovery-mysql
    ports:
      - 8001:8080
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=r2dbc:mysql://root:tomo@discovery-mysql:3306/r2dbc
    networks:
      - common-network

networks:
  common-network:
    driver: bridge
```

### Things that I had tried:

I added networks: -common-network to put into the same network, but didn't work. I don't see anything wrong with the URL `r2dbc:mysql://root:tomo@discovery-mysql:3306/r2dbc`.
By the way, when I run the program locally on IDE (not using docker-compose up), given the `url=r2dbc:mysql://root:tomo@127.0.0.1:3306/r2dbc`, it works fine.

I have seen similar threads on stack overflow, but many of their solutions didn't work (I specified in the "Things that I had tried" section).

What could be the reason that the lead to the error `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`?

### Here are the full details of errors:

```
C:\Users\me\github\HelloWorld>docker-compose up
WARNING: Found orphan containers (mysql) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Starting discovery-mysql ... done
Starting helloworld_flyway_1        ... done
Starting helloworld_discovery-app_1 ... done
Attaching to discovery-mysql, helloworld_flyway_1, helloworld_discovery-app_1
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23 16:03:23+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.34-1debian10 started.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23 16:03:23+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23 16:03:23+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.34-1debian10 started.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.899462Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).

discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.900841Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.34) starting as process 1 ...
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.903779Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.903816Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.903821Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.903824Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.903827Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.903829Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.904263Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.904371Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.905996Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.914593Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.916694Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.928540Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.947396Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.947471Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.978325Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.978805Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.978846Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.979683Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.34 started; log sequence number 12664810
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.979948Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.980060Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.982100Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210623 16:03:23
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.984495Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.984525Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.985024Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.985071Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.985582Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.985650Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.985661Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.985676Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.992611Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.

discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:23.999904Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
discovery-mysql    | 2021-06-23T16:03:24.000165Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
discovery-mysql    | Version: '5.7.34'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
flyway_1           | ERROR: Invalid argument: url=jdbc:mysql://discovery-mysql:3306/r2dbc?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false -user=root -password=tomo migrate
helloworld_flyway_1 exited with code 1
discovery-app_1    | 
discovery-app_1    |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
discovery-app_1    |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
discovery-app_1    | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
discovery-app_1    |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
discovery-app_1    |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
discovery-app_1    |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
discovery-app_1    |  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.0)
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    | 2021-06-23 16:03:25.501  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.t.HelloWorld.HelloWorldApplication     : Starting HelloWorldApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 16.0.1 on 1d485fdb3de3 with PID 1
(/app.jar started by root in /)
discovery-app_1    | 2021-06-23 16:03:25.503  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.t.HelloWorld.HelloWorldApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
discovery-app_1    | 2021-06-23 16:03:26.119  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data R2DBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
discovery-app_1    | 2021-06-23 16:03:26.242  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 118 ms. Found 1 R2DBC repository interfaces.
discovery-app_1    | ****************************************************************************************************************
discovery-app_1    | r2dbc:mysql://root:tomo@discovery-mysql:3306/r2dbc  // System.out.println(@Value("${spring.datasource.url}"))
discovery-app_1    | ****************************************************************************************************************
discovery-app_1    | 2021-06-23 16:03:27.354  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 7.10.0 by Redgate
discovery-app_1    | 2021-06-23 16:03:27.469  WARN 1 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.spring
framework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfi
guration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException:
discovery-app_1    | Unable to obtain connection from database: Communications link failure
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
discovery-app_1    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
discovery-app_1    | SQL State  : 08S01
discovery-app_1    | Error Code : 0
discovery-app_1    | Message    : Communications link failure
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    | 2021-06-23 16:03:27.485  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
discovery-app_1    | 2021-06-23 16:03:27.505 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/Flyw
ayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException:
discovery-app_1    | Unable to obtain connection from database: Communications link failure
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
discovery-app_1    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
discovery-app_1    | SQL State  : 08S01
discovery-app_1    | Error Code : 0
discovery-app_1    | Message    : Communications link failure
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.tomoaki3284.HelloWorld.HelloWorldApplication.main(HelloWorldApplication.java:11) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
discovery-app_1    | Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException:
discovery-app_1    | Unable to obtain connection from database: Communications link failure
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
discovery-app_1    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------
discovery-app_1    | SQL State  : 08S01
discovery-app_1    | Error Code : 0
discovery-app_1    | Message    : Communications link failure
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    |    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:71) ~[flyway-core-7.10.0.jar!/:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:68) ~[flyway-core-7.10.0.jar!/:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:510) ~[flyway-core-7.10.0.jar!/:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:170) ~[flyway-core-7.10.0.jar!/:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    ... 24 common frames omitted
discovery-app_1    | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:144) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.7.jar!/:5.3.7]
discovery-app_1    |    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:55) ~[flyway-core-7.10.0.jar!/:na]
discovery-app_1    |    ... 30 common frames omitted
discovery-app_1    | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
discovery-app_1    |
discovery-app_1    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    ... 37 common frames omitted
discovery-app_1    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:576) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:565) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645) ~[na:na]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]
discovery-app_1    |    ... 40 common frames omitted
discovery-app_1    |

// from here, the same log repeatedly because Spring Boot App would restart on failure.
```

### How I am pushing changes every time:

```
mvnw package && java -jar target/spring-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
docker build -t tomojava3284/helloworldapi .
docker push tomojava3284/helloworldapi:latest
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up
```

Comment: You have a restart policy on the application container; does it eventually come up?  (It can happen that the application starts before the database is fully initialized.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I thought the same first, but however many times I waited for Spring App to restart, it generates the same error.

Comment: I added the full errors and how I am pushing changes (this can be wrong?).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug there when accessing the database by service name. as a solution I can suggest you use `host.docker.internal`.
then the URL will be like the below. it will not be a problem in the production mode due to using a managed database.

```bash
- spring.datasource.url=r2dbc:mysql://root:tomo@host.docker.internal:3306/r2dbc
```

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host

Answer (score -1):

I had a same problem with java and my solution for this issue was setting IP for each service in docker-compose.yml like this :

```
version: '3'

services:

  discovery-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.34
    container_name: discovery-mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=tomo
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=r2dbc
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    networks:
      common-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.5

  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway
    command:
      - url=jdbc:mysql://discovery-mysql:3306/r2dbc?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false -user=root -password=tomo migrate
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources/db/migration:/flyway/sql
      - ./flyway/conf/flyway.config:/flyway.config
    depends_on:
      - discovery-mysql
    networks:
      common-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.10

  discovery-app:
    image: tomojava3284/helloworldapi:latest
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - discovery-mysql
    ports:
      - 8001:8080
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=r2dbc:mysql://root:tomo@discovery-mysql:3306/r2dbc
    networks:
      common-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.15

networks:
  common-network:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.0.0/16
```

And your connect url will be

```
$ r2dbc:mysql://root:tomo@ 172.18.0.5:3306/r2dbc
```

Be careful what IP range you use, maybe this one is no longer free

Comment: It still has the same error, unfortunately. Having the url- `spring.datasource.url=r2dbc:mysql://root:tomo@discovery-mysql:3306/r2dbc` on docker-compose file should stay the same correct? I'm really not sure what is causing this error.